# Play! Morphia querying within Collection (i.e. Set or List) fields

Tags: java, collections, playframework, morphia

I have documents with a Set of Long values for their parent document IDs like so:

```
{..., "parentIDs" : [ 47, 49 ], ...}
```

In my Entity class this field is defined as:

```
@Embedded(concreteClass = java.util.TreeSet.class)
@Indexed
public Set<Long> parentIDs = new TreeSet<Long>();
```

What would be the Morphia query to return all documents with a specific parent ID (for example 47)?

I'm using:

```
List<Node> nl = Node.find("type", "event").filter("parentIDs", id).asList();
```

with id being a correct and existing parent document id.
But it does not work. What am I missing?

thanks eriq

Comment: BTW, your query could be simplified as: List<Node> nl = Node.find("parentIDs,type", id, "event").asList();

Answer (score 2):

I am not really familiar with the find expression and I am not using Play! But I the way I solve this problem should work for you as well. Instead of using filter, use the methods field() and hasThisOne() .

Could be something like this:

```
Node.find("type","event").field("parentIDs").hasThisOne(id).asList();
```

Hope this helps

Regards
arne

Comment: Thanks for your help! The problem results from another point in my code. I found out .filter("parentIDs", id).asList(); works as well.